# Configure Postfix to send email on ubuntu

Tags: postfix-mta

I'm trying to config a postfix server to use for notifications of some my scripts.
The server should be able only to send email, not to receive them.

I'm within a company network.

I'm using a fake mail address to send the email.

Actually I can send email (and receive it to my true mail address) but postfix tries to send the same email to the the address I uses to send it (and it doesn't exist) creating an infinite queue.

Could someone help me to fix it?

this is my main.cf

```
    # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


    # Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
    # line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
    # is /etc/mailname.
    #myorigin = /etc/mailname

    smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
    biff = no

    # appending .domain is the MUA's job.
    append_dot_mydomain = no

    # Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
    #delay_warning_time = 4h

    readme_directory = no

    # TLS parameters
    smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
    smtpd_use_tls=yes
    smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
    smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

    # See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
    # information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

    smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
    myhostname = srvsviluppocentrale
    alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
    alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
    mydomain = agenziamobilita.roma.it
    myorigin = $mydomain
    mydestination =
    relayhost = [srvw04.rsm.local]:25
    relay =
    # mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
    mailbox_size_limit = 0
    recipient_delimiter = +
    inet_interfaces = loopback-only
    inet_protocols = all

    # sender_canonical_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
```

Comment: Maybe research this on https://superuser.com or Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Post logs of what is failing.  Hard to diagnose any issues with only config.  Also, the `myhostname` parameter should be FQDN.